# How to disable mod_authn_file in apache2 loaded modules

Tags: apache

I disable the module using the `a2dismod` command in htaccess file. Here is the command, I tried to disable for both.

```
    a2dismod mod_authn_file
(OR)
    a2dismod authn_file_module
```

I got an error in my apache log,

```
.htaccess: Invalid command 'a2dismod', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `a2dismod` in a `htaccess` file? `a2dismod` is a command AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS you are using?

On CentOS there are no a2enmod and a2dismod commands. To disable unneeded modules in Apache you need to carry out steps as described at the lower end of - for instance - this post:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-disable-apache-modules-under-linux-unix/

Comment: Then this link will be helpful to you.